# Receiving UDP message while processing a deque

Tags: python, sockets, simultaneous

In an attempt to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743984/my-program-doesnt-receive-messages-while-processing-the-list), I'm trying to simplify the problem. Suppose I have a receiver listening to both TCP and UDP messages. It will receive several strings, append them to a deque and after receiving `"finish"` message, it will start processing the deque.

If I receive a UDP message, I need to stop the processing, remove the last item of deque and then continue the processing.

```
from collections import deque

host = commands.getoutput("hostname -I")
port = 5005
backlog = 5
BUFSIZE = 4096
q = deque()


def read_tcp(s):
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected with', *addr)
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        print "received data:", data
        conn.send(data)  # echo
    conn.close()
    if (data == 'finish'):
        processP(q)
    else:
        q.append(data)

def read_udp(s):
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print("received message:", data)
    del q[-1]


processP(q):
    text = q.popleft()
    textReverse = text[::-1]
    print(textReverse)

def run():
    # create tcp socket
    tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        tcp.bind((host,port))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind failed', err)
        return
    tcp.listen(1)
    # create udp socket
    udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    udp.bind((host,port))
    print('***Socket now listening at***:', host, port)
    input = [tcp,udp]
    try:
        while True:
            inputready,outputready,exceptready = select(input,[],[])
            for s in inputready:
                if s == tcp:
                    read_tcp(s)
                elif s == udp:
                    read_udp(s)
                else:
                    print("unknown socket:", s)
    # Hit Break / Ctrl-C to exit
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')
        raise
    tcp.close()
    udp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I have problem in **pausing the program upon receiving a UDP message and then returning to the processing phase**. Right now, if a UDP message is sent to my program while processing, it won't receive the message until the end of processing (and then the deque is empty). I thought maybe threading or multiprocessing may help, but I can't figure out how to apply them to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody forces you to empty out the dequeue. You can check if an UDP message has arrived before dequeueing the next workload. And that is as far as you can get with threads, as they do not allow you to interrupt arbitrary code. They can always only be terminated cooperatively.

If your single item processing takes too long, then multiprocessing of work-items is an option, as you can *kill* an external process.

Use `select.select` to check for incoming data on your sockets with a short timeout, before continuing to process the next workload. Alternatively you could use a thread waiting on input on the thread and manipulate the dequeue.

*EDIT* This is your code made to work with python3, select.select and a timeout. Triggering read_udp works with netcat with `echo foo | nc -4 -u  localhost 5005` but then triggers an exception because you assume the existence of elements in the dequeue - which is an application logic problem that is independent of the question how to interleave listening and working.

```
import socket
import select
from collections import deque

host = "localhost"
port = 5005
backlog = 5
BUFSIZE = 4096
q = deque()


def read_tcp(s):
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected with', *addr)
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        print("received data:", data)
        conn.send(data)  # echo
    conn.close()
    if (data == 'finish'):
        processP(q)
    else:
        q.append(data)

def read_udp(s):
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print("received message:", data)
    del q[-1]


def processP(q):
    text = q.popleft()
    textReverse = text[::-1]
    print(textReverse)

def run():
    # create tcp socket
    tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        tcp.bind((host,port))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind failed', err)
        return
    tcp.listen(1)
    # create udp socket
    udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    udp.bind((host,port))
    print('***Socket now listening at***:', host, port)
    input = [tcp,udp]
    try:
        while True:
            print("select.select")
            inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],[], 0.1)
            for s in inputready:
                if s == tcp:
                    read_tcp(s)
                elif s == udp:
                    read_udp(s)
                else:
                    print("unknown socket:", s)
    # Hit Break / Ctrl-C to exit
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')
        raise
    tcp.close()
    udp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: How can check if a UDP message has arrived before dequeueing the next workload?

Comment: Using the select call on the socket is one option. I augmented my answer to that extend.

Comment: Sorry if my question is obvious, I'm new to python. So here since I send `q` as an input to `processP(q)` for processing, should I put `select.select` at the beginning of my `processP(q)` function?

Comment: That would be one option, yes. But I would rather put it into read_tcp, and rename that to "read_sockets". As you should also pass your tcp socket there. select is a general mechanism to learn if data has come in from streams, together with an optional timeout that you also need becaues eventually you want to continue processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm reading [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) to see how to use `select.select`, but I'm a little confused. Is it possible for you to edit your answer with how I should place it in my code?

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I send a TCP message to this host, I'm receiving an error `TypeError: read_tcp() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: This is not something I can observe in your above code, as it clearly does NOT take 3 arguments. so I can’t comment on that.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was my mistake :)